# Does $TS$ being an isomorphism imply that $S$ is an isomorphism?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $V, W, U$ be vector spaces over a field $\Bbb F$, and suppose that $S : V → W$ and $T : W → U$ are linear.

If $TS$ is an isomorphism, is it true that $S$ must be an isomorphism?

If it's not true, what is a counterexample?

Comment: Note that "$S$ is isomorphic" is not a common way of saying "$S$ is an isomorphism".

Answer (score 3):

This is not true.  A counterexample with matrices:
$$
S = \pmatrix{1\\0},\quad T = \pmatrix{1&0}
$$
That is, we have $S(x) = (x,0)$, and $T(x,y) = x$.

---

A more generally useful statement: $S$ is injective if and only if it has a left-inverse, and $T$ is surjective if and only if it has a right-inverse.

Answer (score 1):

If $TS$ is an isomorphism, then $\dim(V)=\dim(U)=n$ we can notice that this would be impossible whenever $\dim(W)< n$, since $rank(TS)\le rank(S) \le \dim(W)$

So we are left with $\dim(W) \ge n$ automatically. However, if $\dim(W) >n$, it would be impossible for $S$ to be an isomorphism, since $rank(S)\le \dim (V)<\dim(W)$

So the only chance you have for $S$ to be an isomorphism would be when $\dim(W)=n$, the real question you should ask yourself is "must $S$ be an isomorphism" under this condition?